# Docusign tabs not sized same is uploaded fillable pdf field

Tags: docusignapi

I want to upload fillable PDFs (with form fields) to DocuSign, create and send envelope. I know DocuSign recognizes uploaded pdf form fields and transforms them to appropriate Tabs. Tabs are sized matching to size of pdf fields.

In my case DocuSign Tabs are sized incorrectly. Tab are too wide, going beyond the document width and causing one tab overlapping to another tab on side. Tab height is also not matching. See screenshot below showing fillable PDF vs how tabs look when uploaded to DouSign.

Refer tab for **Name of Employer** textbox. Its is too wide, overlapping to Policy number field on right and has too much height.

**This is original fillable PDF**

[image]

**This is how it looks on DocuSign**
[image]

Do you what could cause this kind of discrepancy? The fillable pdf has Adobe PDF Version 1.5. Any suggestion or hint is much appreciated.

Comment: Just want to add direction question. DocuSign uses what property of pdf form field to determine fields position and dimension?

Comment: Hello Rakesh. When converting form fields to DS tags, they come through to the DocuSign side with a set of values like `<TextField Name="Date" Value="" DefaultValue="" MaxLength="none" ReadOnly="False" Tooltip="" Required="Optional"  ><Position Top="243" Bottom="219" Left="322" Right="532" Width="210" Height="24" />`, however I'm not sure what that looks like on your side. 
I've opened a Support Case for this request. Can you email your PDF file to go-live@docusign.com and reference Case #07166503?
Thanks!

Comment: @Drew apologies for delay in response. I sent email with pdf attached to reproduce the issue

Comment: Thanks, I've provided that to our Documents team for investigation. In the mean time, to work around this issue you may consider creating a template, fixing the tags and applying that template to envelopes you are sending using this document.